Man searching for his girlfriend and partner in crime with the help of another girl
The movie starts of in an open road where a cop car (or maybe more than one, but I think one cop car because it's like those old heist movies with not much cops in the area, country, western like) is chasing another car with a guy and girl in it (the area based on the movie is open, meaning a lot of trees not much houses, not also much cars on the road, country like). The guy tells the girl to jump out of the car and escape (or I think she takes whatever they stole, diamonds my guess), and she jumps out of the car (she jumps and lands on the grass, cause it's open veldt), watching him drive off while still being chased! (I think he is headed to cross the border).
Later he seeks out to find her because he wants the diamonds. Upon looking for her he sees a young, pregnant (not sure), light skinned black woman (the woman is very beautiful, I think she got green eyes, and wearing a dress, she is standing by the road) on the road. He stops to pick her up (but first he drives past, then reverse to pick her up), but she pulls out a gun saying that she knows what men want and she would rather take his car (but she's scared holding the gun, not experienced in guns, she pulls the gun from her purse). He walks a few steps forward (he says she must shoot if she wants, cause the guy knows she won't) and she accidentally shoots (when she shoots, she's like omg). He says watch it (and takes the gun), she's like sorry and they both jump in the car. He gets flashbacks about his girlfriend (like there is a sex scene) and tells the girl about her.
It's getting late and they stop at a friend's house (the friends lives like in the woods, like no other houses around, in a wooden house) to spend the night(they chat, have a drink and show him a shot gun, they talk of old times, it's his best friend), but while the girl is sleeping, the friend tried to rape her (he's like "I know you want this"), but is shot from behind (he turns around to see the guy with the gun, falls, and says "sorry, it gets lonely out here"). They leave.
Later, the guy meets up with his girlfriend (who he was tracking) and they both end up dying next to each other (they kill each other but they love each other very much so they they die happily hand in hand).
(The whole reason why they fight and kill each other, is because he tries to contact her once he escaped from the cops but she was nowhere to be found, and she doesn't even call him or keep in touch with him, that's why he is on the road searching for her, and she just wants to keep the diamonds cause she knows once it's sold she can be be rich, so the fight for the diamonds.)
The hitchhiker girl is then shown driving away with the diamonds (which he gave her to keep during the fight) looking at the two dead lovers in the car mirror looking sad cause she really bonded with the guy. (The girl is now heading to cross the border with the stolen diamonds (cause at the front you can see the police and the border gate).
I watched this movie on E TV (a South African channel). It's a Hollywood movie, and has an 18snvl rating. I believe that it's a 1990s movie. It was played alongside Babel and Basic Instinct with the same age rating at the same time slot (10:30pm+).

I think you've provided more than enough information. Thanks!

@coleopterist, I did put in more info, but it sort of vanished, but atleast u get the picture

The problem was that your recent edits unfortunately did more bad than good as you worsened many of the improvements done to the question and didn't provide so much more info that was really neccessary. As coleopterist said, it is really pretty detailed already. But your enthusiasm is apreciated. ;-)

Ok guys and girls,any info will be fine, if there is a link, evens better,

@christian rau, thanks, I don't think any ask sites would be so cool, besides other sites would want be to lessen the details

Last question, how long does my question stay opened for, and what happens if no answer, say after 5 days?

Your question stays alive forever. It isn't deleted or removed for any reason (other than being off-topic or invalid, which this one isn't). There can always be answers given to it. And even if you accepted an answer as the correct one, the question will not vanish and there can always be new answers added (which for an identification question would make too much sense, though). The site is not just about getting the asker help with his temporary problem, but also to provide an ever growing resource of information, so questions won't get removed out of nothing.

But for identification questions like this one there is indeed a special rule that might get it deletes it if it stays for too long (don't know, some months maybe) without any answer given or any response by the asker on already given answers. Though I'd need to ask a moderator what the exact conditions for that are. See here for further information.

@Christian Rau , but see how you can help, like I said ask around, post it on other sites , all help is appriciated

Just be sure to stay tuned and don't get too impatient. It may take some days or weeks until you get an answer to the question, if any. But like said, your question has good prerequisits to get a good answer if there's anybody around here that knows this movie.

@Larenzo_03 When (approx month/year) did you watch it?

@nben plont,  I watched it last year

I think what may help to answer my question would be to think about movies with a similar plot, even if the movie has a similar scene from the ubove lister then I can view them and maybe it might be that one

The hitchhicking lady(black one) looks similar to KELLE STEWART and TANYA WRIGHT, just abit younger and she also has that chubby checks!

Guys I just founds the movie name, its called Cold Around the Heart starring David Carusso and Kelly Lynch. Go check it out, and you will see my plot was exactly correct.

You should enter links to your movie so others can easily find it, then select your own answer as "the" answer.

How did you find it?

I posted the question on askmehelpdesk @NGLN and they found it
